# Is there a way to find text in visual studio code's cell outputs for jupyter notebooks?

Tags: visual-studio, jupyter-notebook, find

Visual studio code will allow me to find text in the python code chunks; however, it won't search in the outputs of the cells. Any way around this?

Comment: This seems to be a known problem. Covered by VS Code Issues https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94239 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/128665. Timeline for a corretion is not clear to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

Yes, there's a simple checkbox `Cell Output` you must tick in the filter options. [Source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94239#issuecomment-1347590495).

[image]

Comment: spot on, but this was not working a year ago :-)